# no puedo acceder a process.env nodejs

Tags: nodejs, rest, jwt

Estoy empezando a programar en node, y como parte de mis tareas tengo que programar una app con autenticacion mediante token.

Pero estoy atorado en la parte en la que la genera, porque si le paso el texto directo en el campo "key" del jwt-simple si me genera el token sin problemas... pero si intento pasarle el contenido de process.env me dice que requiere el key.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');  
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');  
var app = express();  
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));  
app.use(bodyparser.json());  
var connection = require('./connection');  
var routes = require('./routes');  
var server = app.listen(8000, function() {  
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + server.address().port);  
});
connection.init();  
routes.configure(app);
```

**config.js**

```
module.exports={  
    TOKEN_SECRET:process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || "tokenultrasecreto"  
};
```

**post.js**

```
app.post('/todo/search/', function(req, res){       
var enviado=req.body.name;          
        todo.busca(req, res);  
    });
```

**todo.js**

```
this.busca = function(req,res) {  
    var id=req.body.name;  
    var idmy;  
    var name;  
    var pass=req.body.pass;  
    var list = [];  
    connection.acquire(function(err, con)/*1*/ {  
var cadena='select * from todo_list where name = \''+[id]+'\' and password=\''+[pass]+'\';';  
          console.log(cadena);  
          con.query(cadena, function(err, result) {  
        con.release();      
        console.log(id);        
        if (err) {  
            throw err;  
        } else {      
            idmy=result;  
            if(idmy.length > 0){  
                name=idmy[0].name;  
                pass=idmy[0].pass;  
                res.status(400).send({message:'Eureka!', token: service.createToken(id)});  
            }else{  
                console.log('Registro no encontrado');  
                res.status(400).send({message:'Registro no encontrado'});               
            }  
        }  
      });  
    });  

  };

var jwt=require('jwt-simple');  
var moment=require('moment');  
var config=('./config');  
var algorithm = 'HS256';  
exports.createToken=function(user){  
    var payload={  
        sub:user.id,  
        iat:moment().unix(),  
        exp:moment().add(1, "days").unix(),  
    };  
    console.log('Llega a services');  
    console.log(config.TOKEN_SECRET);  
    return jwt.encode(payload, config.TOKEN_SECRET);  
    //return jwt.encode(payload, 'Hola');  
};
```

Espero que no tenga demasiados errores de principiante jajaja  Saludos!!

Comment: Saludos @Hamoru-San Bgp, revisa este articulo acerca de como se deben formular las preguntas (seguro te ayuda a plantear mejor tu pregunta) http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Creo olvidaste el `require` al importar `config.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí puedes acceder a las variables de entorno. Tu problema se sebe a que no estás importando realmente a `config.js`:

```
var config=('./config');
```

Para importar un módulo usando CommonJS se usa la función [`require`](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1):

```
const config = require('./config');
```

Si estás usando [módulos nativos de JS (ES6)](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-modules-in-depth) se usan las palabras `import` y `from`:

```
import config from './config';
```

Comment: Si funcionó.Gracias!!!

Comment: Considera votar y marcar mi respuesta si te pareció correcta. Un saludo.